# Installing a theme on the sub domain of a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, themes, subdomain

I am working on a WordPress site which is hosted. I have created a sub domain on that site using CPanel. Now I want to Install a theme in the sub site and I am not able to do it. I tried the following

1. In the Admin Dashboard, goto Appearances->Themes, Upload Zip Folder. **But this would only Install the theme on the Main site and not the subsite.**
2. Try to manually upload the file to the sub domain folder through my hosting provider. **It doesn't** **work**.

Kindly suggest ways on how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you already install WordPress at the subdomain? You should simply be able to log into the dashboard for that install (e.g. at http://subdomain.example.com/wp-admin/), and add the theme there. It should not affect the main site at all. (Both sites are entirely unrelated.)

(If you're using the multisite feature, things are a bit different. In that case, you should enable it through the network admin dashboard before you can activate it on any site.)

Comment: No I have not Installed WordPress at the subdomain. I will try doing that. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to upload theme in sub domain and display it on your main website page?